# How can I print the nth line of a file, and detect whether the process failed?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file called `namelist` with names like this:

```
george
cindy
chester
```

I'm using `nl namelist` to produce:

```
1 george
2 cindy
3 chester
```

I want to use that name list in a script that contains something like this:

```
while [ true ]; do
read -p "Who are you? " NAMEID
NAME="$(sed ''"$NAMEID"'q;d' namelist)
if $NAME; 
    then
        echo "Hello."
        return
    else
        echo "Sorry, that's not a valid name."
fi
done
```

wherein `$NAMEID` has valid values of 1, 2, and 3.  I'd like `$NAME` to be false if `$NAMEID` is anything other than 1, 2, or 3, such as 97 or fasdhj.  `sed` always gives me an exit value of `0`.  `awk 'NR==$NAMEID {print; err = 1}' namelist` does the same.

Right now I'm using OS X 10.11, but I'm planning to use Ubuntu 16.04 when I finish the script.

Comment: `[ -z "$NAME" ]` ? And check that `$NAMEID` is numeric. Or use `select` if your shell has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `NAME` variable definition so that it returns the person's name, and we can test on that.  The first thought might be something like

```
NAME="$(sed -n "${NAMEID}p" namelist)"
```

But this has potential problems with NAMEID holding bad data (what if someone enters "hello" or "-10"..).

So instead we'll use `awk` instead:

```
NAME="$(awk -vNAMEID="$NAMEID" 'NR==NAMEID { print ; exit }' namelist)"
```

Now it'll be empty if the value is out of range, or hold the user's name.

```
$ cat namelist
george
cindy
chester

$ cat tstscript
getname()
{
  while [ true ]; do
    read -p "Who are you? " NAMEID
    NAME="$(awk -vNAMEID="$NAMEID" 'NR==NAMEID { print ; exit }' namelist)"

    if [ -n "$NAME" ]
    then
      echo "Hello $NAME."
      return
    else
      echo "Sorry, that's not a valid name."
    fi
  done
}

getname

$ bash tstscript 
Who are you? 4
Sorry, that's not a valid name.
Who are you? hello
Sorry, that's not a valid name.
Who are you? -45
Sorry, that's not a valid name.
Who are you? 2
Hello cindy.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, POSIXly:

```
id=$NAMEID awk '$1 == ENVIRON["id"] {x = 1;print;}; END { exit !x}' <file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 1 | id=1 awk '$1 == ENVIRON["id"] {x = 1;print;}; END { exit !x}'
1
$ echo "$?"
0

$ echo 1 | id=2 awk '$1 == ENVIRON["id"] {x = 1;print;}; END { exit !x}'
$ echo "$?"
1
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n -e "$NAMEID{p;q;}' -e '$q1'
```

Comment: With the `sed`, what if `NAMEID=hello` ?  Or begins with a `-` ?

Comment: @StephenHarris: Of course it won't work. Maybe safer to change to `/$NAMEID/`